# Maven dependencies for REST API - Jersey - Glassfish or not?

Tags: java, rest, maven, glassfish, jersey

I'm new to REST API and little familiar with Maven. I noticed that most people use REST with Jersey implementation. I need to write POST requests and might also need GET requests as well. I have difficulty finding out the right - minimum required - dependencies for Maven to start coding.

I looked at many resources online. Looks like Jersey comes with Glassfish Server. I have Tomcat installed on my local PC which I'm going to use for development of REST and testing. We have Jboss running on our production servers which my code eventually will be deployed to. It looks to me that different resources say different things or there are chances I'm not getting it!

1) Can I use Jersey with Tomcat or Jboss WITHOUT any dependency on Glassfish?

2) Back to the Maven dependencies;

Here I found:

http://aike.me/site/blog/20090914/restful_web-services_in_java_using_jax-rs_-_part_1_getting_up_and_running

```
Maven: Getting Jersey into your project

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.12</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Are these would be ALL I need?

B/c in Jersey website I found different dependencies defined:

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html

I won't copy and paste those dependencies here b/c it makes this post very long. I do NOT see any of these dependencies - mentioned in http://aike.me defined in:

https://jersey.java.net

Such as:

```
<artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>

<artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>

<artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>

<artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
```

Why is that? Why I'm being referred to different dependencies?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a dependency with "org.glassfish.*" in group id doesn't mean you have to use Glassfish server.

Jersey has become a part of glassfish and that's the only reason the package name has changed. The newest versions are released under this package and it is recommended on the Jersey website so I would stick with the newest packages.

Comment: In my question, I'm asking about Glassfish server and not Glassfish jars; at the time, the question was posted, I was using Jersey1, however, org.glassfish.jersey are for the versions 2 and above, but overall, I think this answer makes sense, which means: if one uses the Jersey implementations, they don't necessarily need to use Glassfish server, they can use Tomcat, JBoss, ... and if using Jersey1 is not a must, then better to use the latest jar files and packages from org.glassfish.jersey.

Answer (score -1):

I have created a quick start template for the same, feel free to fork or clone it.
[Get it here](https://github.com/skohli0302/jims.git)

Comment: Thanks Sid. I started using what's mentioned in http://aike.me/site/blog/20090914/restful_web-services_in_java_using_jax-rs_-_part_1_getting_up_and_running However, the question is that why https://jersey.java.net which is the home of Jersey project, should simply NOT have a section as if: "Maven users who do not use Glassfish, use these dependencies..." or something like that and minimize much confusion. Its not mentioned how one should go ahead with Jersey w/o Glassfish and how they should configure Maven for that matter in Jersey website, the place you expect to find it at the first place.

Comment: Agree, I find that strange as well. Also, com.sun - that's like a small time travel, taking me to the happy days of JavaOne. I expected a different package name.